# Gridview with Horizontal and Veritcal center align dividers

Tags: android, gridview

I need to design the grid view as shown in the picture below.

[image: Grid View]

```
I have implemented Custom GridView with Images and used the below code for GridView -

<GridView
android:id="@+id/gridViewBloodDonors"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:numColumns="2"
android:background="#e5e5e5"
android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:listSelector="@null"
android:verticalSpacing="1dp" />
```

and below code for the ImageView for GridView-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="5dp" 
android:background="#FFF">

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/grid_button"
android:layout_width="140dp"
android:layout_height="100dp" />
</LinearLayout>

And the result I got as shown in the picture below
```

[image: GridView]

Can anyone please help me with the divider. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

forget the gridview and remove existing borders.

Instead add to each cell, below (or above) each icon, some element like a `<div>` and apply a css width and border and centering as necessary.

you can do something similar to create a vertical line - either add a third, center column that contains a css styled div, or add some element after the column1 icons or before the column2 icons.

You just have to play with the styling when it comes to first/last conditions.  For instance you don't want bottom lines on the last row.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to design custom ItemDecorator for half divider.

or else you can also
Use,

```
<View android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="0.60"
      android:gravity="centre" 
      android:layout_height="0.3dp"
      android:background="#777" />
```

this will be used for bottom divider, place this in item_layout.xml file, similarly you can create a right side divider.

Answer (score 0):

For Some who is unable to solve this problem:
Lets create two different layer-list as background borders. and then you can make some of the side lines as transparent.

In recyclerView Adapter, you can put condition to hider and show the background borders:

background_left:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:left="-2dp"
        android:top="-2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">

            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And

background_right:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:left="-2dp"
        android:right="-2dp"
        android:top="-2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">

            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Finally, In your adapter:

```
public class YourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<YourAdapter.MyVieHolder> {
    ...

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyVieHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewholder_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new MyVieHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyVieHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int position) {
        
        holder.llItemLayout.setBackground(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.getResources(), position % 2 == 0 ? R.drawable.background_left:R.drawable.background_right, context.getTheme()));
        
    }
    
    ...
}
```